# How to cost a researcher for a funding application?

Tags: funding

When you apply for academic/research funding, how exactly do you cost someone?

For instance, you want to have a research assistant working 1 day a week. Do you just divide annual salary of standard RA by five? Do you do the same for any other type of collaborator, like a post-doc, or an assistant professor? Such is the method suggested in [this site](https://intranet.birmingham.ac.uk/finance/fEC/Costing/example.aspx). Or is there a more elaborated mechanism to decide that?

Anyone with experience on this? It's my first time applying for funding.

Comment: Is there a department / internal organisation at your university that could help you with finances and costing? I just recently attended some events meant for early-career academics applying for funding, and the general advice we were given was "Talk to XY about your funding section, they are there to help you"

Comment: Your university almost certainly has a standard formula for this - ask your grants office.

Comment: thank you both. @penelope Still, for the sake of SE Q&A style, are there many options available, in order to make them organisation specific? I guess I'm asking for basic principles.

Comment: The differ a lot from funding agency to funding agency and country to country.

Answer (score 3):

**Your institution/the institution that will host the project almost certainly has a grants office for the department/school faculty. You absolutely need to be in contact to do this costing as the institution almost certainly has policies and systems to deal with this that you MUST use if the institution is to sign off on your application.**

You don't say which country you are talking about, so let me answer for the UK.

There are two ways to add the costs of a person to a grant application in the UK:

**Types of cost**

Directly Allocated Costs and Directly Incurred Costs.

DI costs are the easiest to explain. A DI cost is when the university has to spend money it would not otherwise have spent. So - buying equipment for the study, or travel costs etc.

DA costs are where the university allocates a fraction of a resource it already pays for to the new project. So, for example, if a professor spends 10% of there time on the grant, then 10% of the prof's salary is "Allocated" to the grant. Universities like DA costs because they attract overheads, where as DI costs don't. Of course, this counts against you because it makes your grant more expensive to the funders.

So, when you cost up a person on a grant, you need to decide DA or DI. Generally, if you are allocating a part of the time of someone already employed by the university, it will be a DA cost. If you are hiring someone new, then it is a DI cost (there are exceptions to this, but in general).

For people that are already employed by the university, the university will have on its systems a "day rate" for that person. I.e. how much the university charges to have that person allocated to a project for a day. You then multiply this by the number of days a person will spend on the project.

For new people, the university will often have a set number of salary points at which they can be appointed, with an associated pre-calculated cost.

Our university has a costing tool that does all these calculations for you (and indeed, its use is mandatory, as it ensures that you have added all the correct extras, overheads, etc).

**Costing a fraction of a person**

Funders generally want to know how much time a person will spend on a project. It is common to express this as either % FTE (Full Time equivalent) or hours. So one day a week would be 20% FTE, or about 340 hour a year.

If you are employing someone the university already employs, then this is easy. You say "The university will allocate 20% of Jane  Doe's time to the project."

If you are going the DI route, then this is harder, because they reviewer might well say

"You want someone who has all these super advanced skills, but you will only employ them for 20% of there time for 18 months? Where on earth are you going to find someone who will agree to that?".

The alternative is you can name someone, even if they are not already employed. So you might say "We request salary and costs for 340 hours for a Dr. Chaudhuri to be employed as a research assistant, who will perform the vital roles of x, y and z".

My experience is that the more advanced the skills you want, the more skeptical reviewers will be of small FTEs, but that naming someone can go quite a long way to offsetting that. So 50% of an unnammed pre-doctoral technician is probably fine, but 20% of an unknown advanced software engineer is not, how ever 50% of the proven software engineer Dr. Alverez is probably okay.

Comment: Superb. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The key difficulty is to figure out how to pay or employ someone on a grant. Once you know that, the cost should follow in a straightforward way.

An important first question is whether this research assistant is to become a staff member at your institution or not (maybe doing contract work). If the person is to become staff, you have to figure out which employment category and conditions apply, for example regarding employment percentages or employment durations - does that fit to what you need for the project?

It may be not so easy to employ someone on a 20 % position only, unless it's a student maybe. An alternative may be to look for someone who is not fully employed currently and may be topped up, or someone who is fully employed but where part of the salary (and tasks) could be allocated to your grant.

Once you know the staff category and any conditions, it should be easy to get the cost. If in doubt ask your staff department or financial administrator for it. They can maybe also do a salary simulation over the time range of the project, which is especially useful if the person to work on the project is already known and specific conditions apply.